# Error in packaging a smart contract on IBM Blockchain Platform Visual Studio Extension

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, visual-studio-extensions, ibp-vscode-extension

To create a sample smart contract, I have followed the process in the link below:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform

In the step of 'Package a smart contract project,' the following error occurred: 
[ERROR] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/..../node_modules/.bin/fabric-chaincode-node'

Under the /.bin directory, actually the fabric-chaincode-node is not found. Is the fabric code verson/release in my environment  not met to what VSCode extension requires?

Comment: Please show the full name of the folder in the error.  Are you using a Mac?  What version of VSCode are you running?  What version of the IBM Extension? Are you using the debugger?

Comment: You could try opening a terminal window to the folder containing the contract and running "npm install"

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled node version 10 and installed node version 8. Create the contract again and re build package . It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It really looks for the module under ./bin 
Thus, try installing fabric-shim module manually using npm i fabric-shim.

Answer (score 0):

Run below two command in `Chaincode`

```
nvm use v8.17.0

npm install
```